# How to find and replace mixing format text in MS-Word or using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is an example of what I want. Suppose a text:

paper<sup>[1]</sup>, some texts<sup>[2]</sup>, paper<sup>[3]</sup>

Here is the expected result ==>

paper[1], some texts<sup>[2]</sup>, paper[3]

That is, I want to replace all "paper<sup>[1]</sup>" with "paper[1]" and similarly, replace "paper<sup>[3]</sup>" with "paper[3]" but keep the texts<sup>[2]</sup> unchanged.

I have noticed that word can not search the mixing format text, e.g., I can not find the text "paper<sup>[3]</sup>". So I may need the VBA to achieve this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need VBA for that! A *wildcard* Find/Replace can be used, where:

```
Find = paper\[[13]\]
Replace = ^&
```

and the replacement font is set to 'not superscript'. If you really want a macro, record the above.